# Default visibility of class methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop, visibility

I looked at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), but I can't seem to find the answer.

What is the default visibility in PHP for methods without a visibility declaration? Does PHP have a package visibility like in Java?

For example, in the following code, is `go()` public or private?

```
class test {
  function go() {
  }
}
```

The reason I asked is that I've seen many constructors code written as `function __construct()` and some as `public function __construct()`. Are they equivalent?

Comment: DOCS in 2021: **`Class properties must be defined as public, private, or protected. If declared using var, the property will be defined as public.`**

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Default is public.

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: Same goes for properties

Comment: Same goes for constants.

Comment: This was changed over time, it's now  "must" not a "may". Also *usually* you don't need public properties and lot of times it's a code smell.

Answer (score 27):

Default is public. It's a good practice to always include it, however PHP4 supported classes without access modifiers, so it's common to see no usage of them in legacy code.

And no, PHP has no package visibility, mainly because until recently PHP had no packages.

Comment: @Ian: I would say because "explicit is better than implicit" (as the [Zen of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228181/the-zen-of-python) says).  It causes other programmers to waste brain cycles wondering if the constructor is private or public or what.  If people always used access modifiers the original poster might not even have asked this question.

Comment: Also of note, on languages such as Java, were the default is package-private, one always wonders if it's package-private by design, or the developer just forgot to specify it (specially when dealing with not-so-senior developers). That's why PMD includes rules such as this: https://pmd.github.io/pmd-5.5.2/pmd-java/rules/java/comments.html#CommentDefaultAccessModifier

Comment: @User therefore Python made everything just public and do the whatever hack you want with it x)

Answer (score 12):

The default is public. The reason probably is backwards compatibility as old code expects it to be public (it would stop working if it weren't public).

Comment: Kudos for the reasoning.

Answer (score 7):

> Default visibility is PUBLIC

[Source](http://www.php5-tutorial.com/classes/visibility/)

Answer (score 2):

When no [visibility](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/oop-visibility) keyword (`public`,`private` or `protected`) used, methods will be **public**. But, you cannot define properties in this way. For [properties](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/oop-properties), you will need to append a visibility keyword on declaration.

For properties which is not declared in the class and you assign a value to it inside a method will have a public visibility.

```
<?php
class Example {
    public $name; 
    public function __construct() {
        $this -> age = 9; // age is now public
        $this -> privateFunction();
    }
    private function privateFunction() {
        $this -> country = "USA"; // this is also public
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`function __construct()` and `public function __construct()` works as same method name.

If you could not define the prefix for a method name, it should be by default public.