# Difference between functions and public functions in classes

Tags: php, function, class

In classes, most people use `public function name() { }` to define methods. However, I have seen several examples of them being defined without the `public` keyword, like `function name() { }`. I was confused by this because I thought you had to use public/private/protected when inside a class.

I made the same sort of thing and `function` was doing the exact same job as `public function`.

So my question is, what is the difference between using `function` and `public function` when inside a class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default visibility of class methods in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224380/default-visibility-of-class-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Omitting the visibility is **legacy code**. PHP 4 did not support `public`, `protected` and `private`, all methods were `public`.

Short: `"public function" == "function" // true`

See also the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods):

> ```
> // This is public
> function Foo()
> {
>     $this->MyPublic();
>     $this->MyProtected();
>     $this->MyPrivate();
> }
> ```

---

Similarly `var $attribute;` is equivalent to `public $attribute`. The `var` version also is PHP 4 legacy code.

Comment: @Will I said omitting it is **legacy** code, therefore you should *always* explicitly write `public` for clarity and full future compatibility.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you label this as "legacy" code. The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods) is specific: the visibility of a method *may* be define but it is not required, and a suitable default is provided. According to my reading, non-explicit declarations are still valid in new code.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins It has it origins in PHP 4 and exists for backwards compatibility. Other OOP compability functionality already has been axed (namely Constructors named like the class for namespaced classes) and explicitly defining the visibility is the only safe way.

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference in PHP >=5. Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.

Answer (score 4):

When you don't set the visibility of a method in php, it's the same as setting it as public.

From [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/protected):

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods
> declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as
> public.

```
<?php
/**
 * Define MyClass
 */
class MyClass
{
    // Declare a public constructor
    public function __construct() { }

    // Declare a public method
    public function MyPublic() { }

    // Declare a protected method
    protected function MyProtected() { }

    // Declare a private method
    private function MyPrivate() { }

    // This is public
    function Foo()
    {
        $this->MyPublic();
        $this->MyProtected();
        $this->MyPrivate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define with simply `function` means, default it takes `public` scope (default) from **PHP 5**.

```
function sample { }
```

and

```
public function sample { }
```

are **no difference** between them.

`private` => can access the property with in the class

`protected` => can access the property own class and sub classes

`public` => can access anywhere in application.

Answer (score 2):

The [default visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) is public. If a method is declared without an explicit visibility prefix, it will be public.

The following declarations are equivalent:

```
function name() {};

public function name() {};
```

Answer (score 0):

In OOP PHP function are called Methods.

```
  class MyClass {

    public function aMethod() {
    // (do stuff here)
    }
     function myMethod(){} //here public property is assumed

    }
```

When you optionally leave out the public, private, or protected keyword in a class. If you do this, publicis assumed.

- public  -> Available in the whole scope, meaning it can be accessed everywhere
- protected ->Available within the class or its subclasses.
- private ->Available only within the class that defines the function

  These feature is available since php 5.X  and they give you the possibility to control the visibility of your variable or function.

if you see a function with identifiers, like public , protected and private these are in class.

```
public function functionName(){} 

and 
function functionName(){}
```

are basically the same except that one has visibility level
    of being public and is object oriented way and the other php normal function with no visibility level.