# php static methods - what is the difference between "static function" and "public static function"?

Tags: php, static

As the title says i cannot seem to see what the difference is between a public static and just a plain old static.. ie

```
public static function visitorUserCreate( $data  )
    {}
```

and

```
static function visitorUserCreate( $data  )
    {}
```

Both appear to be public, if they are what is the point in declaring public if it is by default?

Comment: No low-level difference. Default access is `public`, but it makes code more readable when you see `public`, and on next line `private`, for two different methods, instead of skipping `public` for first, and see `private` on second

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default visibility of class methods in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224380/default-visibility-of-class-methods-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [PHP manual documentation for Static Keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> For compatibility with PHP 4, if no visibility declaration is used, then the property or method will be treated as if it was declared as public.

To answer your question:

> Both appear to be public, if they are what is the point in declaring public if it is by default?

None. The point of declaring public is for readability. There is no difference at compiler level, however it's usually good design to declare it.

Comment: Underlying question is *"what is the point in declaring public if it is by default?"* Which leads us into a long discussion about why being explicit is important.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. If not declared, it will be public as this is the default behavior. From [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. Methods
>   declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as
>   public.

But, **there is a point**. Here is a quote from [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/):

> Ideally you should write PHP code that adheres to a known standard.
>   This could be any        combination of PSR’s, or one of the coding
>   standards made by PEAR or Zend. This means **other    developers can
>   easily read and work with your code**, and applications that implement
>   the components can have consistency even when working with lots of
>   third-party code.

According to [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), which is one of the approved style recommendations by the [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/):

> **Visibility MUST be declared on all properties and methods**; abstract
>   and final MUST be declared before the visibility; static MUST be
>   declared after the visibility.