# What happens when a method is not declared as public, private, or protected?

Tags: php, class, oop

I've been learning OOP in PHP and I'm wondering what happens when you instantiate a class with functions that are not declared as "public", "private", or "protected"? Here's an example:

```
//file1
class foo {
    function doSomething() {
        return "stuff";
    }
}

//file2
include(file1.php);
$bar = new foo;
```

P.S. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm learning OOP PHP because a website I'm helping develop has been using the dolphin framework heavily and has been using this type of

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224380/default-visibility-of-class-methods-in-php

Comment: Thanks @Dagon. I didn't know visibility was the term used to describe public, private, and protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking what happens? Nothing. You can still use them outside of the class (not private). And you can still overwrite them (not protected).